# Changing position of data in Input file to a .cpp program Changes output unexpectedly

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is what the code is for:
https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA04/problems/STACKS

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    int t; cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n; cin >> n;
        vector<int> a;
        while(n--) {
            int x; cin >> x;
            if(a.empty()) {
                a.push_back(x);
            } else {
                vector<int>::iterator it = upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), x);
                int pos = it - a.begin();
                if(pos == a.size()) {
                    if(a[pos] > x) {
                        a[pos] = x;
                    } else {
                        a.push_back(x);
                    }
                } else {
                    a[pos] = x;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << a.size();
        for(auto e: a) {
            cout << " " << e;
        }
        cout << "\n";

    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Input to this program is:

```
2
6
3 4 5 1 1 2
8
14 5 13 19 17 10 18 12
```

The Unexpected output it generates:

```
3 1 1 2
3 5 10 12
```

If the input is changed to:

```
2
8
14 5 13 19 17 10 18 12
6
3 4 5 1 1 2
```

It shows up correct output:

```
4 5 10 12 18
3 1 1 2
```

The test case with 8 numbers as input if its position is altered in the input file. Then this behavior is observed.

When looking at the run of the code via `gdb`, it gives expected output for both input files, no problem then.

The output is not justified, what am I missing to see?

Comment: Now you need to learn something that online competition/judge sites won't teach: ***Debugging***. Use a debugger to step through your code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values and see how they change.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP says they get the correct result when running with `gdb`. Maybe there's UB somewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096#31816096

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes! I have already, Hence, I mentioned about `gdb`. Used it and went through the entire code step by step, `vector<int> a` at the end of gdb run was showing up expected values. The output only is not coming out correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this check:

```
if(pos == a.size()) {
    if(a[pos] > x) {   // this is UB
```

if the condition is true, then you are indexing into an invalid position of `a`, which invokes undefined behavior.

It seems you want to do

```
if(pos != a.size()) {
```

instead. The conventional way to check for this condition is

```
if(it != a.end()) {
```

Comment: The problem was not in the comparison, it was in the assignment, I did `a[pos] = x` and this was done when condition is `pos == a.size()` BLUNDER!
Replaced it by `a[a.size()-1] = x` and it all works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @amarVashishth Yes, that's what I meant, the incorrect check leads to the UB. See where I marked it in the answer.